# How to create a watermark aligned at an angle？

Tags: python, imagemagick, watermark

---

*Is it possible to draw such watermarks aligned at an angle using Python or Imagemagick ?*

[image]

[<sup>*Source*</sup>](https://www.watermark-software.com/)

---

***Update in July 5 2022 AM :***

```
magick convert input.jpg -gravity center -alpha set -background none ( -pointsize 14 -fill #ffffff64 -size 120x45 label:"SAMPLE TEXT" -write mpr:tile +delete ) ( -clone 0 -resize 200% -colorize 100 -tile mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" -rotate 40 ) -composite output.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, you can do the following. Create an image of the watermark text at the desired angle and color and opacity. Then tile that out to fill the size of the input. The composite the tiled watermark over the input.

Input:

[image]

```
convert \
-background None -fill "#fff7" \
-pointsize 20 label:"Watermark" \
-rotate -40 +repage \
+write mpr:TILE +delete \
barn.jpg -alpha set \
\( +clone -fill mpr:TILE -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) \
-compose over -composite \
barn_watermarked.jpg
```

[image]

If on Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick.